# Why is my python keylogger not recording any keys?

Tags: python

I was following a tutorial on how to make a python keylogger. I followed all the steps and ran the code, but when I started typing, my keylogger wouldn't record anything, while the keylogger in the tutorial worked just fine. Does anyone know why that is? Here is the code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key):
    print("{0} pressed".format(key))

def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Here is the screenshot of what happens:
[image]

I ran the code and typed some text. The program should print the keys I pressed in the terminal below, but, as you can see, there is nothing there.

Comment: I just ran the code and it works fine. What happens when you run it? Does the program terminate immidiately? Does it stop when you press escape key? Maybe you can provide some screenshots.

Comment: even i tried it but it was working fine on my laptop, can you share any screenshot

Answer (score 0):

According to `pyninput` [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html):

> On Mac OSX, one of the following must be true:
>
> - The process must run as root.
> - Your application must be white listed under Enable access for assistive devices. Note that this might require that you package your application, since otherwise the entire Python installation must be white listed.

Comment: I assume you are on Mac OSX because of how the terminal looks :)